# when i try to upload into snowflake , using put command and table stage getting error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Create table statement**

```sql
create table  "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC"."Trips"
(tripduration integer,
  starttime timestamp,
  stoptime timestamp,
  start_station_id integer,
  start_station_name string,
  start_station_latitude float,
  start_station_longitude float,
  end_station_id integer,
  end_station_name string,
  end_station_latitude float,
  end_station_longitude float,
  bikeid integer,
  usertype string,
  birth_year integer,
  gender integer);
```

**PUT command**

```sh
avinash#COMPUTE_WH@DEMO_DB.PUBLIC>put file://C:\Users\lanreddy\Desktop\JC-202002-citibike-tripdata1.csv @%Trips;
 **002003 (02000): SQL compilation error: Stage 'DEMO_DB.PUBLIC."%TRIPS"' does not exist or not authorized.**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the table you used double-quotes around the table name which means it is case sensitive: `create table "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC"."Trips"`. When you do this it means that every time you reference the table now you need to put it in quotes (the table name is Trips and not TRIPS or trips)

Try running this as your `PUT` command:

```sh
COMPUTE_WH@DEMO_DB.PUBLIC> put file://C:\Users\lanreddy\Desktop\JC-202002-citibike-tripdata1.csv @%"Trips";
```

or this:

```sh
COMPUTE_WH@DEMO_DB.PUBLIC> put file://C:\Users\lanreddy\Desktop\JC-202002-citibike-tripdata1.csv @"%Trips";
```

I would recommend never creating your tables with double-quotes. if you change your original `CREATE TABLE` statement to the following then your original `PUT` command will probably work:

```sql
create table  DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.trips
(tripduration integer,
  starttime timestamp,
  stoptime timestamp,
  start_station_id integer,
  start_station_name string,
  start_station_latitude float,
  start_station_longitude float,
  end_station_id integer,
  end_station_name string,
  end_station_latitude float,
  end_station_longitude float,
  bikeid integer,
  usertype string,
  birth_year integer,
  gender integer);
```